# Remove Dead space from SharePoint Modern Team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

In the current Modern Team Site template. It sets the max width of the 'canvas' to `1268px`. This results in there be a large chunk of dead space on the right hand side of the page.

[image]

As there is no script editor web part for the modern site, how do I go about getting rid of this?

Comment: Are you using any custom CSS or script on this page? Also there is a [modern script editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) available developed using SPFx.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, thanks for the quick response. There is nothing custom here, its all out of the box. I did read about a modern script editor built by someone else but I was hoping to keep my site as pure out of the box as possible. :) If I can't then I will grab the modern script editor and apply it. Thanks.

Comment: I have not seen this much of blank space in any of the team sites we are using. Is there any other OOTB webpart which is not loading or nothing to show that's why it is showing blank? Check it bye editing your page. Is there a blank space on all pages of this site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I just created another page, and again it has a large chunk of white space on the left, because of the max-width css property of 1268px. This is again an out of the box page template (visual) which I have used.

https://imgur.com/q3HG1lY

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, we have to use custom code to achieve it.

We can use SPFx Applications Customiser to inject the following CSS style for the modern pages.

```
.CanvasZone{
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

[image]

**Solution with source code**: [SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using custom code I'd recommend having a Communication site. It has considerably less white space by default, which I found more aesthetically pleasing than Teams sites.

[These templates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-and-customize-sharepoint-site-templates-39382463-0e45-4d1b-be27-0e96aeec8398#ID0EDBH=Communication_site_templates) might be helpful to notice the difference between the two types.